# VBA & Excel - Loop eecordset

Tags: vba, excel, loops, recordset

I need to loop an recordset in VBA to fill my Excel sheet. I want to do this for each row.

What I've got now is:

```
comm.CommandText = str_SQL
rec.Open comm
Sheets("mySheet").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rec
```

This works. But I want to change the color of the cell when the index `change` in my rec is `X`.

Is this possbile? Has someone got another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far you output all of the `recordsets` contents at once, which is way faster than looping every `field` in every `record` (at least for large recordsets).

**If** you wanted to actually loop, it would would something like this (messy and untested):

```
    Dim i As Integer, j as Integer
    Dim fld As Object

    ' print headers, starting from A4 to the left
    i = 1
    j = 4
    For Each fld In .Fields
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Cells(j, i).Value = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' print record by record, field by field
    i = 1
    j = j + 1
    While Not .EOF
        For Each fld In .Fields
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Cells(j, i).Value = fld.Value
            ' here you could test for something like
            ' If fld.Name = "change" and fld.Value = "X" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            i = i + 1
        Next fld
        j = j + 1
        .MoveNext
    Wend
```

This can be streamlined quite some more, but generally, you would have to use *two* nested loops for the records, and for the fields in each record. Which might be too clumsy for what you try to do.

A more reasonable approach would be to use something simple like

```
Dim cell As Object
For Each cell In Sheets("mySheet").UsedRange '<- replaced UsedRange with the column where "change" is printed, if there's the possibility that "X" is in other columns aswell
    With cell
        If .Value = "X" Then .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
Next cell
```

to just format your cells, independent of your already processed recordset, or add conditional formatting to said range (with vba), which has the advantage of updating itself

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.